# Not Getting refresh token as a part of response after the Auth 2.0 Login Authorization code for google actions

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, authorization, actions-on-google

Google actions AuthO 2.0 not getting refresh token

After successful login with my web application i get the access token in response.

where can i get the refresh token on actions-on-google side?

The Flow is Authorization_Code and not implicit.

After successful user authentication, in the first response where can i see the refresh token?

Is it possible to get the refresh token?

I am asking the user to signIn if access token is not present.**How can i get the refresh token as a part of the code response, if it's a part of http response, how can you access it when GET request is done by googl-actions in background.**

```
if (isNullOrUndefined(conv.user.access.token)) 
{        
conv.ask(new SignIn('To get your account details'));      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Google requires that you provide the special parameter `access_type=offline` if you need a refresh token. You need to include that in the authorization URL to receive a refresh token.

Google's [Refresh Token docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline):

> If you are not using a client library, you need to set the `access_type` HTTP query parameter to `offline` when redirecting the user to Google's OAuth 2.0 server. In that case, Google's authorization server returns a refresh token when you exchange an authorization code for an access token. Then, if the access token expires (or at any other time), you can use a refresh token to obtain a new access token.

Note that Google will not issue refresh tokens for users that have already authorized an application unless you also include the `prompt=consent` parameter, forcing the user to affirmatively re-consent to the application's access.